# Create rewrite conditions for two types of query string URLs

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have two types of query string URLs that I am having trouble creating rewrites for in my htaccess file. The first URL type is **/component/afcatrades/109165?view=profile**. I am needing to remove the query string **?view=profile** and rewrite it to this URL type **http://www.afca.ab.ca/links/afca-trade-members/profile/%1**, where the **%1** is the profile ID. I have come up with the following rewrite rule, but it is not working. What needs to be adjusted to make it work?

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/([0-9]+)$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^view=profile$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.afca.ab.ca/links/afca-trade-members/profile/%1 [L,R=301]
```

The second URL type is **book-store?page=shop.product_details&flypage=flypage-ask.tpl&product_id=4410&category_id=11**. I am needing to remove the query string **?page=shop.product_details&flypage=flypage-ask.tpl&product_id=4410&category_id=11** and rewrite it to this URL type **http://www.afca.ab.ca/book-store/delmar-cengage-nelson-education**, where the last segment of the URL is the book store category that is associated with the **category_id**. The **product_id** can be any 0-9 value and does not need to be connected to a specific product on the new website. I just need it to redirect to the product's category. I have included the rewrite rule I have come up with, but again it is not working.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} page=shop.product_details&flypage=flypage-ask.tpl&product_id=([0-9]+)$&category_id=11
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.afca.ab.ca/book-store/delmar-cengage-nelson-education? [R=301,L]
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Whats not working for you?

Comment: @starkeen The first URL is being rewritten to this **http://www.afca.ab.ca/links/afca-trade-members/109165?view=profile** and the page is blank, which means there are errors.

The second URL is not being rewritten and it loads the content from this page **http://www.afca.ab.ca/book-store** at this URL **http://www.afca.ab.ca/bookstore?page=shop.product_details&flypage=flypage-ask.tpl&product_id=4456&category_id=11**, which is shown in the browser address bar.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^view=profile$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/component/afcatrades/([0-9]+)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /links/afca-trade-members/profile/%1? [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/book-store
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} page=shop.product_details&flypage=flypage-ask.tpl&product_id=([0-9]+)&category_id=11
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /book-store/delmar-cengage-nelson-education? [R=301,L]
```

Comment: The first rewrite is displaying as **http://www.afca.ab.ca/links/afca-trade-members/800792?view=profile** in the address bar. As you can see the query string is not being removed and profile is not being added as a segment to the URL.

The second rewrite is not removing the query string either. The address is being displayed as **http://www.afca.ab.ca/book-store?page=shop.product_details&flypage=flypage-ask.tpl&product_id=4410&category_id=11** instead of **http://www.afca.ab.ca/book-store/delmar-cengage-nelson-education**.

Comment: Strange, the question mark at the end of RewriteRule should take care of removing query string (and it does so on my test server). What is your apache version?

Comment: The server is using Apache 2.2.22. This rewrite is working. It has the same base URL as the profile. The URL being redirected is: **http://afca.ab.ca/component/afcatrades/?view=list**.

`RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} view=list
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.afca.ab.ca/links/afca-trade-members? [R=301,L]`